Do we lose generality by making this assumption?
Problem : We consider the inscribed pentagon ABCDE in which AB = BC = CD and centroid of the pentagon coincides with the center of the circumscribed circle. Show that
pentagon ABCDE is regular.
My question is : Is there any problem if I assume that the pentagon is inscribed in the unit circle and the affixes of points A,B are 1 and $\cos \frac{2 \pi}{5} + i \sin\frac{2 \pi}{5} $, I think we do not lose generality if we fix a single segment but I need a confirmation that by making this assumption we can solve without a lose from the generality of the problem.Would mean a lot to me if someone could help me.Thanks!
Why I think we don't lose the generality : whether the segment is of length l, we can resize the 2 points to have the required size, more precisely $|1-\cos \frac{2 \pi}{5} + i \sin\frac{2 \pi}{5} |$, and then we can rotate the pentagon so that the affixes of the points at the ends of the segment are 1 and $\cos \frac{2 \pi}{5} + i \sin\frac{2 \pi}{5} $. All I did was to apply some transformations that do not change the generality of the problem, but I am waiting to see what you think.

“Centroid” is “center of mass”, right?

yes , so in complex geometry is the arithmetic mean of the affixes.

You seem to be already assuming that the pentagon is regular by putting $B$ at that specific distance from $A$.

Well, imagine that we have a pentagon with the given property. can't we resize it so that the side you are talking about can be transformed so that it has exactly the desired length?

An easy planimetric reasoning could be made to prove that. I suppose, you are interested exactly in complex-numbers reasoning?

Yes .And more precisely if solving with the consideration made solves the problem for any general case.

If you simply resized to fix the side length, wouldn't you have to resize the unit circle as well? So you'd lose the assumption that the pentagon is inscribed in the unit circle? It seems like you can either assume the side length is a given value, or that the pentagon is inscribed in the unit circle, but assuming both requires some sort of proof.

@MartianInvader is there a way we can prove that we can assume both ?

That the pentagon has a circumscribed circle (i.e., is cyclic) is required by the language of the question, so no generality is lost by assuming that the circle may taken as the unit circle in the complex plane and that the vertices of the pentagon are complex numbers with unit magnitude.
However, the fact that three consecutive sides have equal length does not imply that the angle/argument between two consecutive vertices is $2\pi/5$.  All you can say is that these angles are equal, because equal sides subtend equal angle measures in a cyclic polygon.
Thus, the most you can assume without loss of generality is that $A = 1$, $B = e^{i\theta}$, $C = e^{2i\theta}$, $D = e^{3i\theta}$, and $E = e^{i\varphi}$ where $3\theta < \varphi < 2\pi$.

Thank you for clarifying!
